# Unable to access a Google Play Developer account

Tags: android, google-play

I am unable to access my Google Play Developer account since this morning. I had three apps which were running smoothly until today. But now, none of them are in Google Play listing. Can someone help me out on how to resolve this issue?

I tried contact Google but got no response. I also tried to submit an appeal but no response again. I would be very grateful to someone who's got an answer for my query. [This is what my error message says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdJfK.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about accessing a third party account, not about coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Developer accounts can only be reinstated if they were disabled by mistake. If your account was disabled due to a violation of Google's Terms of Service, it's no longer eligible to be reinstated by Google's support team.

When your developer account is terminated, you'll no longer be able to publish new applications. You shouldn't attempt to register for a new Google Play Developer Console account since Google can no longer accept applications from you. This means that any related accounts are also permanently suspended, and any new accounts that you try to open will be terminated without a refund of the developer registration fee.

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2491922

Comment: Hi , thanks for your response. I dont find a text saying that I have violated Google TOS . And they never sent me a warning mail before suspending my account. Can that happen ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing Google can help you with here. As stated in the Help article you're being redirected to, _"Your access to this Google product has been suspended because of a perceived violation of either the Google Terms of Service or product-specific Terms of Service."_ Google reserves the right to terminate an account at any time, for any reason, without notice.

Comment: So I should open a new developer account ?? Also, can you enlighten me if I can open a developer account from a different PC and upload my apps through my mac which I did the same for my earlier account ? Does this put me into trouble again ?

Comment: When your developer account is terminated, you'll no longer be able to publish new applications. You shouldn't attempt to register for a new Google Play Developer Console account since Google can no longer accept applications from you. This means that any related accounts are also permanently suspended, and any new accounts that you try to open will be terminated without a refund of the developer registration fee. 
Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2491922

Comment: I get that point aygul. So let me put it this way, if I'm asking my friend to open a developer account and then I put all my apps that were existing in my previous account on the new one. will that be still valid? (provided I change my package name and not the app name). Will I be able to do a workaround with this one ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't comment on any workarounds that are aiming to violate the Google Terms of Service. Of course, you can try, but there is no guarantee this won't put you in trouble again...

Comment: Alright.. Thanks a lot aygul. Your timely response , much appreciated ! I will look into creating a new one, dusting all the apps with proper codes and assets and making sure it doesn't violate the TOS.